# Connecting to Azure SQLDW in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

There is an Azure SQL Data Warehouse that I need to connect to for a linked service in Azure Data Factory. The ADW only supports `Active Directory - Integrated` authentication. How can I connect in Azure Data Factory with this authentication?  The only options in Azure Data Factory are `SQL Authentication`, `Managed Identity` and `Service Principal`.

We have credentials for individual users, not app. I have an AAD app registration we could possibly use.  Do I need to have the ADW add our AAD app?

I tried `SQL Authentication` (obviously didn't work), we don't have a managed instance (would be our ADF instance), and don't have an obvious service principal.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps at this link, and create a Managed Identity for your ADF.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse#managed-identity

Managed Identity (AAD authorisation) is not Managed Instance (database service).